# SVG - how to calculate x and y coordinates after changing scale?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have such SVG:

```html
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="630"
  height="430"
>
  <rect
    rx="0"
    ry="0"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    fill="rgba(92, 95, 108, 1.0)"
  />
    <line x1="0" y1="176" x2="630" y2="176" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
      <g
        transform="scale(0.2) translate(1300.370746612549 818.9994964599609)"
        style="outline: black solid 2px;"
      >
        <path
          fill="rgba(198, 199, 205, 1.0)"
          d="M414.578,62.68L93.932,122.853c-22.91,4.448-33.326,15.876-33.326,35.457v221.359    c0,19.581,6.1,39.759,32.654,35.457l154.561-29.073l-9.639,63.268l110.875-82.335l65.695-12.019    c23.564-4.135,36.643-15.875,36.643-35.457V98.137C451.395,78.556,434.16,62.68,414.578,62.68z M354.711,235.385    c-5.002,53.956-55.426,97.697-112.623,97.697c-57.203,0-99.508-43.741-94.506-97.697c5.004-53.969,55.428-97.711,112.623-97.711    C317.408,137.674,359.721,181.416,354.711,235.385z M215.049,282.888c-3.109-20.511-6.363-56.128-9.063-76.632    c-1.416-10.769,4.857-14.876,15.098-12.905c28.838,5.537,82.398,16.59,82.398,16.59c11.623,1.416,17.576,11.9,6.578,20.643    c-19.873,15.793-56.912,48.904-78.846,61.547C224.207,296.168,216.229,290.638,215.049,282.888z"
        />
      </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see, there is a group element with a scale of `0.2`. Also, this group is "touching" the line. This is fine. However, after changing the scale to `0.25`, the group element suddenly moves into different location.

```html
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="630"
  height="430"
>
  <rect
    rx="0"
    ry="0"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    fill="rgba(92, 95, 108, 1.0)"
  />
    <line x1="0" y1="176" x2="630" y2="176" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
      <g
        transform="scale(0.25) translate(1300.370746612549 818.9994964599609)"
        style="outline: black solid 2px;"
      >
        <path
          fill="rgba(198, 199, 205, 1.0)"
          d="M414.578,62.68L93.932,122.853c-22.91,4.448-33.326,15.876-33.326,35.457v221.359    c0,19.581,6.1,39.759,32.654,35.457l154.561-29.073l-9.639,63.268l110.875-82.335l65.695-12.019    c23.564-4.135,36.643-15.875,36.643-35.457V98.137C451.395,78.556,434.16,62.68,414.578,62.68z M354.711,235.385    c-5.002,53.956-55.426,97.697-112.623,97.697c-57.203,0-99.508-43.741-94.506-97.697c5.004-53.969,55.428-97.711,112.623-97.711    C317.408,137.674,359.721,181.416,354.711,235.385z M215.049,282.888c-3.109-20.511-6.363-56.128-9.063-76.632    c-1.416-10.769,4.857-14.876,15.098-12.905c28.838,5.537,82.398,16.59,82.398,16.59c11.623,1.416,17.576,11.9,6.578,20.643    c-19.873,15.793-56.912,48.904-78.846,61.547C224.207,296.168,216.229,290.638,215.049,282.888z"
        />
      </g>
</svg>
```

My question is: how to update x and y coordinates so that the group is still touching the line?

Comment: You can't change the scale and expect it to be in the same place... You should read a little about scale, take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale

Comment: Yes, that's what I've noticed. My question is: is it somehow mathematically possible to recalculate new x and y coordinates so that the group is still touching the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. temporarily remove the transform attribute completely
2. find out the upper left corner of the path element
3. move the path such that its upper left corner sits at (0, 0)
4. define a transform attribute that *translates* the group to the place where you want the upper left corner to sit permanently
5. *to the right* in the transform attribute, define the *scale* of your choice.

```html
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="630"
  height="430"
>
  <rect
    rx="0"
    ry="0"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    fill="rgba(92, 95, 108, 1.0)"
  />
    <line x1="0" y1="176" x2="630" y2="176" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
      <g
        transform="translate(260 176) scale(0.25)"
        style="outline: black solid 2px;"
      >
        <path transform="translate(-60.6, -62.7)"
          fill="rgba(198, 199, 205, 1.0)"
          d="M414.578,62.68L93.932,122.853c-22.91,4.448-33.326,15.876-33.326,35.457v221.359    c0,19.581,6.1,39.759,32.654,35.457l154.561-29.073l-9.639,63.268l110.875-82.335l65.695-12.019    c23.564-4.135,36.643-15.875,36.643-35.457V98.137C451.395,78.556,434.16,62.68,414.578,62.68z M354.711,235.385    c-5.002,53.956-55.426,97.697-112.623,97.697c-57.203,0-99.508-43.741-94.506-97.697c5.004-53.969,55.428-97.711,112.623-97.711    C317.408,137.674,359.721,181.416,354.711,235.385z M215.049,282.888c-3.109-20.511-6.363-56.128-9.063-76.632    c-1.416-10.769,4.857-14.876,15.098-12.905c28.838,5.537,82.398,16.59,82.398,16.59c11.623,1.416,17.576,11.9,6.578,20.643    c-19.873,15.793-56.912,48.904-78.846,61.547C224.207,296.168,216.229,290.638,215.049,282.888z"
        />
      </g>
</svg>
```

So, how do you find out the upper left corner of the path element? Load it into a browser and, on the Javascript command line, execute

```
document.querySelector('path').getBBox()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!!! Is it possible to only change the scale and then calculate new x / y coordinates? I am curious where that gap from scale 0.2 to 0.25 comes from.

Comment: All scale operations in SVG are relative to the origin of the local coordinate system of the element they are applied to. If a transform attribute has multiple transform functions, they are, if expressed as matrices, [post-multiplied](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#NestedTransformations) to previous transforms. In short: `translate(260 176) scale(0.25)` is equivalent to `matrix(0.25 0 0 0.25 260 176)`, while `scale(0.25) translate(260 176)` is equivalent to `matrix(0.25 0 0 0.25 65 44)`

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution: I'm putting the path inside the g element and I'm scaling the path. I'm using `theg.getBBox()` values to change the x and y of the `<use>` element.

```js
let bb = testg.getBBox()
let x = 315 - bb.x - bb.width/2;
let y = 176 - bb.y;
theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"x", x);
theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"y", y);

theRange.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
  thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", `scale(${parseInt(theRange.value)/100})`)
  let bb = testg.getBBox()
  let x = 315 - bb.x - bb.width/2;
  let y = 176 - bb.y;
  theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"x", x);
  theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"y", y);
})
```

```html
<input id="theRange" type="range" value ="25" /><svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="630"
  height="430"
>
  
  <defs>   
    <g id="testg">
    <path id="thePath" transform="scale(.45)"
          fill="rgba(198, 199, 205, 1.0)"
          d="M414.578,62.68L93.932,122.853c-22.91,4.448-33.326,15.876-33.326,35.457v221.359    c0,19.581,6.1,39.759,32.654,35.457l154.561-29.073l-9.639,63.268l110.875-82.335l65.695-12.019    c23.564-4.135,36.643-15.875,36.643-35.457V98.137C451.395,78.556,434.16,62.68,414.578,62.68z M354.711,235.385    c-5.002,53.956-55.426,97.697-112.623,97.697c-57.203,0-99.508-43.741-94.506-97.697c5.004-53.969,55.428-97.711,112.623-97.711    C317.408,137.674,359.721,181.416,354.711,235.385z M215.049,282.888c-3.109-20.511-6.363-56.128-9.063-76.632    c-1.416-10.769,4.857-14.876,15.098-12.905c28.838,5.537,82.398,16.59,82.398,16.59c11.623,1.416,17.576,11.9,6.578,20.643    c-19.873,15.793-56.912,48.904-78.846,61.547C224.207,296.168,216.229,290.638,215.049,282.888z"
          /></g>
  </defs>
  <rect
    rx="0"
    ry="0"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    fill="rgba(92, 95, 108, 1.0)"
  />
    <line x1="0" y1="176" x2="630" y2="176" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
<line x1="315" y1="0" x2="315" y2="100%" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
       <use id="theUse" xlink:href="#testg"  y="161" />

</svg>
```